# How to integrate Etilize data with Magento

Tags: xml, magento, csv, integration

We have a ecommerce website build with Magento platform, and selling consuming electronics. Before, we are input the porduct manually, and import the data by ourselves.

The situation is, as there thounds of products need to be updated, we want to use the service of Etilize, to provide us the porduct in rich content. However, Etilize only provide the data(CSV file or XML file), the data format is very different from the Magento data format, so that we can't use the data from Etilize directly.

Question: 1. how to integrate the date from Etilize with the Magento data format? so that we can import the data directly.

2. Can it be done by just change the format of the CSV file or XML file?
3. If this job can be done by any non-techincial person, or it has to be done by a programmer?
4. If there is any solution, it will be a software application? or a Plug-in from Magento? I checked on magento, seems there is no such plug-in available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following link may help you. You need to register first and then login.

http://docs.etilize.com/spexlive/demo-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Etlize has a Magento connector extension: http://www.etilize.com/uk/etilize-inc-announces-magento-product-data-importer.html